# Why I can't remove this dir /usr/src/linux?

Tags: linux, shell, centos6.5

When I'm trying to install lvs for linux, I installed kernel-devl  and
I got this   `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/` dir.

Then I make `ln -s /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/ /usr/src/linux`
I found a thing make me confused;

In normal, /usr/src/linux gonna be a soft link.
but when I tried to delete /usr/src/linux. The content all gone but the dir
can't be deleted.

And, /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/
 became empty.and
both of these dir can't be removed, why this happened?
[image]

Comment: This would probably be better at http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh, it's because `linux` is not a directory, so `rm` doesn't like `rm -rf linux/`. Take off the `-r` and it will show you an error message that `-r` suppressed. If you want to delete the symbolic link, just do `rm linux`.

Comment: linux -> /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/   finally i got it. when i make ln -s to /linx,,,itz became a soft link and also a dir.  so rm linux/ didnt work,and error message linux/ is a dir. Cuz some files from ln -s  in it.so i usr rm -r linux /  and it works .but sitll dont know why when i remove linux/ and the dir  /usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64/ also became empty??

Comment: Wait wait wait... I _really_ hope you didn’t type `rm -r linux /` exactly that way. That would delete your `linux` link and everything else on your filesystem. As for removing `linux/`, that isn’t really a location. `linux` is a file that links to another location, like a shortcut file in Windows. Adding the `/` asks the computer to go into the directory that `linux` points to: `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-642.3.1.el6.x86_64`. That is your one and only directory here. `linux` doesn’t store any files. It just links to them.

Comment: I get the impression that you aren’t very familiar with symbolic links. If I’m correct, you might benefit from creating a directory with a few files and subdirectories, and then play around with creating links using `ln -s`. Look at the directory with `ls` and pay attention to the coloring: cyan is for links, dark blue is for real directories. Delete the links, move them, do whatever you can think of and see what happens. It’s not too tricky if you get a bit of experience with it. Just test things out on files that you don’t care about, so it won’t matter if you end up deleting them.

Comment: thanks, i  just begin this.and i also tried rm -rf  /  for fun. hahahaa...but nothing happened.cuz it will add --no-preserve-root to skip safe mode

Comment: Haha, I didn’t know about that option. You’re braver than I am...

Comment: http://lambdaops.com/rm-rf-remains/